# Rails Pretty URL with Decimals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that allows searches using longitude and latitude. I have added a 'pretty' route with:

```
map.connect 'stores/near/:longitude/:latitude', :controller => 'stores', :action => 'index'
```

This works for integer latitude and longitude values (**http://localhost:3000/stores/near/-88/49**) but fails for decimal values (**http://localhost:3000/stores/near/-88.341/49.123**) giving:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/stores/near/-88/49.0" with {:method=>:get}
```

Any ideas how to use pretty URLs in rails with decimals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :requirements => { :param_name => pattern_regex }  param.

```
DECIMAL_PATTERN = /\A-?\d+(\.\d+)\z/.freeze
map.connect 'stores/near/:longitude/:latitude', 
  :controller => 'stores', :action => 'index',
  :requirements => { :longitude => DECIMAL_PATTERN, :latitude => DECIMAL_PATTERN }
```

[Parameters with dots on the URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600207/parameters-with-dots-on-the-uri)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting the same message as before the update. When running 'rake routes' I get:

GET  /stores/near/:longitude/:latitude  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"stores", :requirement=>{:longitude=>/\A-?\d+(\.\d+)\z/, :latitude=>/\A-?\d+(\.\d+)\z/}}

Comment: :requirement *typo* it's :requirements

Comment: Thanks! That helped! The final solution required modifying the regular expression to be: '/-?\d+(\.\d+)/' (the application complained that 'anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements'). Really appreciate the solution and help!