# Rails 3.1 route doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following route and the following url:

```
routes.rb
match '/api/get-items-by-bounded-box/:sw_latitude/:sw_longitude/:ne_latitude/:ne_longitude' => 'api#get_items_by_bounded_box'


http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/get-items-by-bounded-box/33.94/-118.41/34.00/-118.56
```

but get a routing error `(No route matches [GET] "/api/get-items-by-bounded-box/33.94/-118.41/34.00/-118.56")`. Are my named segments wrong? Everything else seems to work fine. Any idea what might be going on?

thx

**edit 1**

```
Tue Dec 27$ rake routes | grep 'get-items'
                           /api/get-items-by-bounded-box/:sw_latitude/:sw_longitude/:ne_latitude/:ne_longitude(.:format) {:controller=>"api", :action=>"get_items_by_bounded_box"}
Tue Dec 27$
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after that? Changes in routes.rb are not picked up automatically.

Comment: yes - I've done that many times but think there is something off with my syntax

Comment: please post output of `rake routes | grep "get-item"` and report if it doesnt return anything!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the decimals, this would probably work

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/get-items-by-bounded-box/33/118/34/118
```

so you could escape the decimals:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/get-items-by-bounded-box/33%2E94/-118%2E41/34%2E00/-118%2E56
```

although that's fairly ugly...maybe check out some other workaronuds for routes with decimals: 
[Rails Pretty URL with Decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648727/rails-pretty-url-with-decimals)